# Angular 8. How to pass a service from the constructor to outside the class but in the same file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I'm creating a routing module called Client Migration Routing module that loads routes dynamically. I'm doing that outside the class but inside the file so I can lazy load the parent component in the AppRouting Module. How can I use the router and moduleMetaDataService outside the class but inside the file? or any other approach?

```
const componentClassMap = [
    ClientMigrationAboutComponent,
    ClientMigrationAllMigrationsComponent,
    ClientMigrationAuditTraceComponent,
    ClientMigrationDeletedMigrationsComponent,
    ClientMigrationMyMigrationsComponent
]

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ClientMigrationComponent,
        canActivate: [RegularUserGuardService],
        children: getChildren()
    }
    
]

function getChildren() {
    let arr = [];
    const moduleNameMetadata = 'client_migration';
    const moduleTitleMetaData = 'Client Migration';
    const moduleComponents = this.moduleMetaData.getModuleComponents(moduleNameMetadata, 'all');
    
    for (const moduleComponent of moduleComponents) {
        const componentClass = componentClassMap[moduleComponent.class_name];
        
        if (componentClass) {
            routes.push({
                path: moduleComponent.route,
                component: componentClass,
                canActivate: [RegularUserGuardService],
                data: {
                    moduleName : moduleNameMetadata,
                    moduleTitle : moduleTitleMetaData,
                    componentName : moduleComponent.name,
                    componentRoute: moduleComponent.route
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientMigrationRoutingModule {
    constructor(private router: Router, private moduleMetaDataService: ModuleMetadataService) {}
}
```

Comment: You can use directly using the class name and create a variable of it

Comment: of the service?

Comment: have you tried declaring service as public in the constructor